# ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC Redirect to page at Program.cs

Tags: c#, redirect

I created a "Coming Soon" page and for the time-being I want all traffic to be routed to this page until I change it.

I would like this redirect to occur within the *Program.cs* file and not in any controller or layout page.

I added the following code (see below) and the site does redirect to the Coming Soon page but with this error message: `redirected too many times`

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Request.Scheme = "https";
        context.Response.Redirect("/ComingSoon");
        return next();
    });
}
```

How can I fix this?

Here is the rest of my Program.cs code

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            builder.Services.AddSession(options => {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            });

            builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            });



            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"] == "https")
                {
                    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
                }
                return next();
            });

           if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.Use((context, next) =>
                {
                    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
                    context.Response.Redirect("/ComingSoon");
                    return next();
                });
            }            

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're redirecting *every* request, meaning when you navigate to `/ComingSoon`, you're redirecting right back to it

You need to check if the path **isn't** coming soon

```cs
    app.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path != "ComingSoon")
        {
            context.Request.Scheme = "https";
            context.Response.Redirect("/ComingSoon");
        }

        return next();
    });
```